# Can I update the modified date in a row without using triggers?

Tags: oracle, oracle10g

There is a modified date column in my table, For each row i want to change the modified date if the row is updated. Can I do this task without using an 'ON UPDATE' trigger?

Comment: I assume you mean a `BEFORE UPDATE` trigger. Or are you using Oracle Forms?

Answer (score 0):

Yes: modify any and all code in your system that runs the UPDATE so that it also updates the modified date.